# How to test parsing a date with SimpleDateFormat without ParseException

Tags: java, android, regex, datetime

I am parsing dates with Android class `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` by passing a specific pattern. However I use multiple data sources and there can be two different date patterns, sometimes there is no day of the week in the date, i.e. I expect to run either one of the two pieces of code:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("EEE dd MMM yyyy", Locale.US).parse(myDate);
new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy", Locale.US).parse(myDate);
```

But I did not find any way to discriminate between these two cases on another criterion than the value of the String `myDate`.

So far, I can run one of the two lines of code and catch the `ParseException` in case I run the wrong one (and I run the other in the catch block). My second option is to do some previous analysis with `String.matches(String)` or manipulating `Pattern`.

As unnecessarily throwing an Exception is a bad practice, and before I reinvent the wheel by implementing the Date parsing tools, is there any other class or library that would let me test a pattern (ideally something like `SimpleDateFormat.isParseable(String)` that would return false if `SimpleDateFormat.parse(String)` throws a ParseException).

So far I searched among SimpleDateFormat methods and its parents, but I could not find any tip or anyone running in such problem.

Here is the current code:

```
Date parseDate(String myDate){
  String expectedDate = "";
  try{
    expectedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE dd MMM yyyy", Locale.US).parse(myDate);
    // this is the first possible pattern for the date
  } catch(ParseException e){ // I consider it bad practice and too expensive to run code there
    expectedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy", Locale.US).parse(myDate);
    // this is the second possible pattern for the date
  }
  return expectedDate;
}
```

And, as I added in a comment, I noticed the issue because I order a list of items displayed in a `ListView` based on their date and I can notice the difference in terms of performance.

Comment: I don't think there's any problem with catching an Exception here. Why do you consider it bad practice? What problem are you trying to avoid?

Comment: In fact, it is mostly because I parse those dates to order the items of a ListView, and I can notice performance issues slowing down the display.

Comment: You might try [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library to compare its performance in parsing. And it offers a [`LocalDate`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) class to handle a date-only value without time-of-day or time zone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the comments on the question, you've identified a performance issue in using `SimpleDateFormat`.

If it's a 50/50 split of each format you could try using a regex to preparse.

```
SimpleDateFormat shortFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "dd MMM yyyy" );
SimpleDateFormat longFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "EEE dd MMM yyyy" );
String input = ""; // from somewhere
Pattern shortFormatPattern = Pattern.compile( "[0-9]{2}\\s\p{Alpha}{3}\\s[0-9]{4}" );
Date date;
if( shortFormatPattern .matcher( input ).matches() )
{
    date = shortFormat.parse( input );
}
else
{
    date = longFormat.parse( input );
}
```

If a significantly large percentage of your input is one format, you could ensure you're attempting to parse that one first (because most of the time, an exception won't be thrown).

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid I have to go with a pattern as you suggest. I guess there is unfortunately no better solution.

Comment: Thanks to you two for your suggestions, I decided to go with stripping the string to the minimum that keeps the date, with Pattern/Matcher (i.e. dd MMM yyyy), and then performing the date parsing.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this by using regular expressions, or, if you wanted to keep it simple and you know that these are the only 2 formats in which you would receive this data, you could always just use a simple split:

```
int parts = myDate.split(' ').length;

if ( parts == 3 ) {
    // short format
}
else if ( parts == 4 ) {
    // long format
}
```

If you're just looking for a quick and dirty way to get it done, this would work. This is far from ideal and should not be used if there is a chance that you may be adding more formats in the future. Ideally, you would store the date format pattern and its regex pattern externally, in a .properties file for example, instead of hard-coding it so that you could expand on it in the future without having to rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for. I have provided an example below to parse date information between 2 formats.

```
SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
java.util.Date date = null;
try 
{
    date = format1.parse("2011-03-27T09:39:01.607");
}
catch (ParseException e) 
{

    e.printStackTrace();
}
SimpleDateFormat format2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMM dd, yyyy");
String newDateStr = format2.format(date);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not really no. I update the question with code to illustrate the issue.